# CodeIgniter error showing core file path instead of the working file path

Tags: php, codeigniter, error-handling

Just wonder how I can setup the system in CodeIgniter so all error path and line number directly shows to my working file instead of any core file path, filename and line number.

For instance I'm having error on file

```
Filename: application\core\MY_Model.php

Line Number: 59
```

but it showing error on

```
You must use the "set" method to update an entry

Filename: D:\xampp\htdocs\ci\system\database\DB_active_rec.php

Line Number: 1174
```

This is in my index.php file on the root

```
switch(dirname(__FILE__)) {
    case 'D:\xampp\htdocs\ci':
        define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');
    break;

    default:
        define('ENVIRONMENT', 'production');
    break;
}
```

Comment: what are your config settings ?

Answer (score 0):

As the above error suggests, there is an error in mysql query formation. Active Records Query are formed in DB library called `DB_active_rec`. So actually though the error is in `core\MY_Model.php` but it belongs to the line where function from `DB_active_rec` Class gets called.

So i don’t see any issue in the above error path.

Comment: Yes that I understood but why it is not showing the working file MY_Model.php instead of core file path?

This way sometime it becomes hard to find the error code..

Comment: I believe that is the flow of program. In situations like this, you can try error stacktracing